Laravel 404 not found error : cannot found a class even though it already been made
I starting to learn php and laravel to make a website. I create a view class named inputdata. From this class, I want to make a route to another view class named KelompokSupir. To connect them, I make a controller class named DatapenggunaController. Here is the code :
public function groupAnalysis(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('groupAnalysis method called');
        
        $kategori = $request->query('kategori');
        $tglFrom = $request->query('tgl_from');
        $tglTo = $request->query('tgl_to');

        $query = Datapengguna::query();

        if ($kategori) {
            $query->where('jabatan', $kategori);
        }

        if ($tglFrom && $tglTo) {
            $query->whereBetween('tgllahir', [$tglFrom, $tglTo]);
        }

        $datapenggunas = $query->get();

        $avg_penggunas = $datapenggunas->map(function ($pengguna) {
            $totalRataRata = $pengguna->datapengukurans->sum('ratarata');
            $countDatapengukurans = $pengguna->datapengukurans->count();
            $avg_pengguna = $countDatapengukurans ? $totalRataRata / $countDatapengukurans : 0;
            return [
                'nama_observant' => $pengguna->nama_observant,
                'avg_pengguna' => $avg_pengguna
            ];
        });

        return view('kelompokSupir', [
            'avg_penggunas' => $avg_penggunas,
            'title' => 'Kelompok Supir Analysis',
            'kategori' => $kategori,
            'tglFrom' => $tglFrom,
            'tglTo' => $tglTo
        ]);
    }

I also make the route :
Route::get('/Data/KelompokSupir',[DatapenggunaController::class,'groupAnalysis']) > name ('datapengguna.groupAnalysis');

I also make the hyperlink from inputdata class :
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('datapengguna.groupAnalysis')}}">Analisis Data Kelompok</a>
 </li>

The problem is, when I open the link in inputdata class, the 404 error appeared
I've checked the route list, and the link matches the route I made :
GET|HEAD   Data/KelompokSupir ............. datapengguna.groupAnalysis › DatapenggunaController@groupAnalysis

And I already clear the cache using php artisan route:clear and php artisan cache:clear, But the error still happens. Is there any solution to solve the 404 error ?

Are you sure that you have added use Illuminate\Http\Request; to the DatapenggunaController class & use App\Http\Controllers\DatapenggunaController to the web.php file ? Check and reply back.

sorry for answering late. I already made 'use Illuminate\Http\Request;' and ' use App\Http\Controllers\DatapenggunaController' when creating the class, but the error still happening

You need to import use App\Http\Controllers\DatapenggunaController to your route file i.e web.php file as per your route definition. But you are saying that you used it when creating class. Both are not same.

I mean I already import use App\Http\Controllers\DatapenggunaController when I make the route from the beginning, but the error still happening.

@Losbay your route name isn't correct if it's like that: > name ('datapengguna.groupAnalysis');, should be lie ->
